# Check iPod touch generation programmatically

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

I need to know whether an iPod touch is 1st or 2nd generation.

Answer (score 0):

As far a I know, you cannot. The [`UIDevice currentDevice]` only tells you if you´re on an iPod/iPhone/iPad

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to tell is that the antennae cover on the 2nd gen. is oval shaped, not a square.